# Detecting network calls for ads in a browser video players

Tags: javascript, html, video, browser, greasemonkey

I need to write a script where i can detect whether an ad was played in between the time the video was playing? 
I intend to write a javascript code and use Greasemonkey.
Alternatively is it possible to detect the possibility of an ad being played after let's say 2 minutes of video has played.
Is there any other method to detect this?

Comment: Greasemonkey cannot always do this.  A Firefox add-on *might* be able to.  That said, this question is way, *way* too broad for Stack Overflow.  The problem can be quite complicated.

Comment: @BrockAdams can you tell me some cases where Greasemonkey may not be able to do so?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an environment that allows you 'sniff' network traffic from the browser then you may be able to detect one type of video ads - those which use explicit VAST (http://www.iab.com/guidelines/digital-video-ad-serving-template-vast-4-0/) ad requests.

However, not all video ads are delivered this way - the video stream may simply contain the ads itself without any indication to the player that the content in the stream has switched from the main video to an ad. This can be true even for individual user specific targeted ads - the server side can seamlessly (from the players point of view) insert the ad content.

At other extreme, some implementations will actually use a different player, or a second instance of the video player, to play ads, which should make your detection job a bit easier.

I think Brock sums it up well in the comments saying that this is a complicated area and there is probably not a single solution which will address all cases.